LUP.6 DRC ERROR
I got a latch up #6 error while performing a DRC.
LUP.6 { @ Any point inside NMOS source/drain space to the nearest PW STRAP in the same PW <= 30 um @ Any point inside PMOS source/drain space to the nearest NW STRAP in the same NW <= 30 um
I’ve tried putting some guardring it lessened the error however, it didn’t solve the whole problem.

Was your guard ring connected to the correct power rail? Please show your layout as a screenshot.
